# How I can "statistically" tell a value remain constant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pattern-recognition

Assume that there is a person who has three computers which consume power as follows:

1. computer A = 10 watts
2. computer B = 40 watts
3. computer C = 90 watts

So, the person has three options every day when he wants to use a computer.

The data collected for a one-month period of time for this person is as follows:

1. Computer A: Never
2. Computer B: Everyday
3. Computer C: Everyday

Thus, the person every day consumed 130 watts.

**Question:**

**- How I can statistically tell this person has a recurring energy pattern (or value) of consuming 130 watts which is consistent over time?**

Is there any statistical test or do I just need to represent data like this in a table:

1. 10 watts; frequency: 0%
2. 40 watts; frequency: 100%
3. 90 watts; frequency: 100%

Comment: - Is there any statistical test by the following hypothesis?

--- H0: This person statistically follows a constant energy-use pattern

--- Ha: Ho is not true

Comment: Do you have only a single months' output or do you have monthly data over a period of time?